# Problems with keras preprocessing

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, image-preprocessing

HI I'm preprocessing some image data to run in a simple FF network:

I have two options that in my eyes are the same but one performs a lot better than the other:

**Option 1**

I save the images in a directory with correspondent subdirectories and run this:

```
xy_training = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("/content/data/train", image_size=(48,48), color_mode='grayscale',label_mode="int")
xy_validation = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("/content/data/valid", image_size=(48,48), color_mode='grayscale',label_mode="int")
xy_testing = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("/content/data/test", image_size=(48,48), color_mode='grayscale',label_mode="int")
```

**Option 2**
I have the raw arrays of the grayscale images and do this

```
def preprocess(data):
    X = []
    pixels_list = data["pixels"].values
    
    for pixels in pixels_list:
        single_image = np.reshape(pixels.split(" "), (WIDTH,HEIGHT)).astype("float")
        X.append(single_image)
        
    # Convert list to 4D array:
    X = np.expand_dims(np.array(X), -1)
    
    # Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
    X = X / 255.0
    return X

train_images= preprocess(train_data)
valid_images= preprocess(valid_data)
test_images= preprocess(test_data)
```

**Option 2** performs so much better than **Option 1**. Is there a parameter in `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(` i'm not setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory
```

not having a built in normalization function. The other custom function you have is applying normalization, so comparison in not an apple-to-apple one.

You will have to do the normalization in a later step after loading the datasets using image_dataset_from_directory.
Here's a sample code for normalizing after loading a batch dataset:

```
def normalize(image,label):
    image = tf.cast(image/255. ,tf.float32)
    label = tf.cast(label ,tf.float32)

    return image,label

xy_training = xy_training.map(normalize)
xy_validation = xy_validation.map(normalize)
xy_testing = xy_testing.map(normalize)
```